# Changing the time zone in Maya with caldav

Tags: calendar

I'm using Maya to synchronize my calendar (with calDav).
When I synchronize the same calendar on my Android app, I get all events displayed at the right time. But when I do it in Maya, I get the events displayed in the default time zone (UTC I guess).

How can I get the events to be displayed in the right time zone?

Comment: I am also getting this...